# Calcular "Grado del nodo" de una red bipartita

Tags: r, r-bipartite

Estoy realizando mi TFM sobre redes bipartitas y tratando de calcular el grado del nodo en R con la función "degree" obtengo el siguiente error:

**Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :
as.edgelist.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, edgelist matrix, network, or sparse matrix, or list thereof.**

Podríais echarme una mano?

Gracias!!

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
    > mp <- read.csv("matriz_prueba.csv",header=TRUE,row.names=1, sep=";")
    > head(mp)
            AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM
      USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19
      EU   609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17
      IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73
      FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29
      JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79
      DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22
    > mp1 <- as.matrix(mp)
    > mpdf <- Matrix2DF(mp1)
    > names(mpdf)[1] <- "DONANTES"
    > names(mpdf)[2] <- "RECEPTORES"
    > names(mpdf)[3] <- "DONACIONES"
    > print(mpdf)
              DONANTES RECEPTORES DONACIONES
      1       USA        AFG       6686.77
      2       EU         AFG        609.50
      3       IDA        AFG        424.68
      4       FRA        AFG         95.65
      5       JPN        AFG        867.20
      6       DEU        AFG        754.42
      7       GBR        AFG        524.15
      8       GLF        AFG         33.14
      9       ESP        AFG        135.02
      10      AUS        AFG        201.08
        ...
        ...
        ...
     > net <- graph_from_data_frame(d=mpdf,directed=TRUE)
     > degree(net, g=1, gmode="digraph", cmode = ("freeman"))

     Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
     as.edgelist.sna input must be an adjacency matrix/array, edgelist matrix, network, or sparse 
     matrix, or list thereof.
```

Answer (score 1):

RESUELTO:

Resulta que al utilizar la función `degree` utiliza la del paquete `sna`. Para solucionarlo, o se inhabilita el `sna` o bien se utiliza `igraph::degree`.

Gracias!